# OpenCV imread() problem

Tags: qt-creator, opencv, image-processing

I have installed OpenCV lately and I cannot use `imread()`.

This is my code

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(  )
{
    Mat i=imread("home/ali/opencv/lena.png",1);
    namedWindow("a",WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
    imshow("a",i);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my `.pro` file in Qt

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = opencv
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

this is what I receive:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/ali/Downloads/opencv/opencv-3.2.0.www.fileniko.com/opencv-3.2.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 304
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/ali/Downloads/opencv/opencv-3.2.0.www.fileniko.com/opencv-3.2.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:304: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

Press <RETURN> to close this window...
^A
```

Using opencv3.2 ubuntu qt

Comment: So - what happens, exactly? My *guess* is that your filepath is invalid (it needs to be `"/home/ali/opencv/lena.png"` - note the leading `/`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941286/opencv-imread-problem/941291#comment1494300_941286) provided the correct solution:

> So - what happens, exactly? My guess is that your filepath is invalid
>   (it needs to be "`/home/ali/opencv/lena.png`" - note the leading /)

– [**steeldriver**](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) [Jul 30 at 17:17](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941286/opencv-imread-problem/941291#comment1494300_941286)

I changed the path and it worked.